# HTML inside HTML affecting each other

Tags: php, css, html, styles

I've looked around at some other suggestions for my problem and the main suggestion is just to use an iframe...

However! I don't want to use an iframe. Onto the question anyway:

Essentially, I'm making a web based email client for a University team project in PHP and am having some problems with HTML emails... after FINALLY getting emails processed properly I've been looking through a few emails and came across one and the background of the email affected the background colour on the body tag of the website...

I took a look at the original message body and it is just like a regular HTML file, the body tag in the email has some CSS styles on it (including the background colour) so from that somehow the body styles from the email are being applied to the body of my page...

Essentially, what I need to know is if there is any way other than using an iframe to stop the code from affecting anything outside the div that contains the message body...

Thanks!

Comment: An iframe seems to be your best option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've actually pretty much figured this out, this might be helpful for other people, so!

I took more of an in depth look into how gmail does it... and they actually convert the body tag into a div tag...

```
$body = str_replace(array("<body ","</body>"),array("<div ","</div>"),$body);
```

I also used some regular expressions to remove the head, html and doctype sections from the email, I'm still looking into any side affects of doing this but so far through all the emails I've tested it with it's not affected anything! If anyone wants the regular expressions I'm using, just comment on here...

It might not be the most elegant of solutions, but it works it seems!

Comment: If you're going with this kind of substitution, a far better bet would be to use HTML Purifier and to set the parent tag to `<div>`. After all, the incoming HTML cannot be trusted to be safe from XSS attacks.

Answer (score 0):

I would say NO - or no good way. I just checked yahoo mail and they are also using an iframe for the emails. I guess they had more time to think about it :-)

Answer (score 0):

> Essentially, what I need to know is if there is any way other than using an iframe to stop the code from affecting anything outside the div that contains the message body...

Sure, you could write your own HTML parser with javascript that renders the output onto a canvas (e.g. like [htmlcanvas](https://github.com/jamesu/htmlcanvas)). Well, if you've got too much time ;)

Actually iframe looks more practicable to me. Otherwise convert the HTML emails to plain text emails. Those are easy to display (you can offer to display the HTML content in a new tab).

Comment: it doesn't sound like a trivial. better solution is using iframe i suppose.

Answer (score 0):

it's a very  interesting issue really i think about it and actually i think we can solve it using javascript as follow:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div id='email'>
      <!--here we the HTML code of the new page should be placed-->
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

if the code that we want to place is the same code

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    Hi it's me
  </body>
</html>
```

we can then get the code inside the email and delete the HTML tag and the head,body Tags:

```
var email = document.getElementById('email').innerHTML();
```

hope this is helpful... good luck